# Check if dates overlap with dates in same table

Tags: sql, datetime

The table below shows 3 selected rows from the session table which contains 3 sessions for the same doctor on the same day but with different, starting and ending times. 
I want to update the sessionStartTime and sessionEndTime columns of one row in this table while checking whether that sessionStartTime and sessionEndTime overlap other 2 rows. What I need is a correct SQL query for this.

For example, I want to edit the sessionStartTime as 2018-07-08 9:30:00 and sessionEndTime as 2018-07-08 10:30:00 of the row with id=1091 and as the starting time and ending time of this session doesn't overlap with other two row values the two values should be updated.But if I entered the two values sessionStartTime as 2018-07-08 8:20:00 and sessionEndTime as 2018-07-08 9:00:00 of the id=1091 it should not allow it to edit the row as there is already another session with id=1090 which contains the starting and ending time duration.

[image]

this is the query I already tried.

```
SELECT * 
FROM session 
WHERE (sessionDate='2018-07-08 00:00:00') 
  AND (userInfoId=420) 
  AND (   ('2018-07-08 9:30:00'BETWEEN sessionStartTime AND sessionEndTime) 
       OR ('2018-07-08 10:30:00'BETWEEN sessionStartTime AND sessionEndTime )
       OR (sessionStartTime BETWEEN '2018-07-08 9:30:00' AND '2018-07-08 10:30:00'));
```

Comment: MySQL And SQL Server are 2 completely different RDBMS, which are you *really* using? Please retag the correct RDBMS, and only the correct RDBMS.

Comment: Also, what was the query you've tried already? Make sure to include that in your edit when you amend your post with the correct tag(s).

Comment: ... also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask section "Help others reproduce the problem"... Image data does nothing to help us reproducing the problem.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: This could be answered without knowing the DBMS name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you're trying to write an overlap query which is much simpler than you think. Assuming you want to edit row number `1091` you can use the following query to determine if the *desired* start and end dates overlap with existing dates:

```
DECLARE @d1 AS DATETIME = '2018-07-08 09:30:00'
DECLARE @d2 AS DATETIME = '2018-07-08 10:30:00'
SELECT *
FROM session
WHERE userInfoId = 420 -- really?
AND id <> 1091 -- a row always overlaps with itself
AND @d2 > sessionStartTime AND sessionEndTime > @d1 -- overlap test, exclusive end date
```

If this query returns one ore more rows then you have an overlap otherwise you don't. Replace `@d1` and `@d2` with datetime literals, parameters or variables.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. Your query works totally fine and it perfectly solved my problem. I am currently working on a web API developed using java and hibernate. Actually, I was stuck with an HQL query to solve my problem. As I am totally new to hibernate my intention was to first get a solution using SQL query and using that same logic run a query in HQL. And your query was perfectly correct for what I needed.Thank you once again.

Comment: @Paba agreed. SQL before HQL.